# how can join two query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to join two querys into one query.

What retrieved in the first query is a tables with column of `resourceindex` that sorts ascending:

```
String loadRates = "SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE userindex="
            + uindex
            + " ORDER BY rank  DESC";
```

And in the second query, what should retrieved is rows of `resourceindexes`:

```
String loadResources = "SELECT * FROM resourceinfo WHERE resourceindex = "
                    + rs.getInt("resourceindex");
```

How can I combine these into a single query?

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts. [ask] [answer] [Help]

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use old style join but use the keyword join.
2. Never ever write an SQL string like that with concatenation of parameters but use parameters instead.

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM public.resourceinfo" 
            + "   inner join public.ratings ON ratings.resourceindex = resourceinfo.index" 
            + " WHERE ratings.userindex = $1" +
            + " ORDER BY ratings.rank DESC;";
   ```

How you would apply the parameters depend on the language you are using which you didn't tag.

EDIT: If you meant it would also filtered by a resourceindex parameter then add it too as:

```
AND resourceinfo.index = $2
```